# ComboBox Items via Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx

```
 <ComboBox fx:id="schaltung" layoutX="347.0" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="213.0">
          <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <String fx:id="reihe" fx:value="Reihenschaltung" />
                    <String fx:id="parallel" fx:value="Parallelschaltung" />
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
 </ComboBox>
```

I added this to my FXML file because I couldnt figure out where I could add Items to my ComboBox in the SceneBuilder. Is it possible to add items via the SceneBuilder, or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: No, there is no mechanism to do this in SceneBuilder. In general, it usually makes more sense to add these in the controller anyway.

Comment: Also since you seem to be choosing from a limited set of choices, using a enum may be a good idea.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't add items to combobox through SceneBuilder. Either you can add through FXML file as you did or through controller as given below.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    comboBox.getItems().removeAll(comboBox.getItems());
    comboBox.getItems().addAll("Option A", "Option B", "Option C");
    comboBox.getSelectionModel().select("Option B");
}
```

Comment: Only when `Controller implements Initializable`

Comment: I'll take SO over tutorials any day )

Comment: I suggest calling: comboBox.getItems().clear() instead of removeAll.

Answer (score 5):

In response to  saikosen [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35266772/3992939): If Controller does **not** implement `Initializable` you can use :

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    comboBox.getItems().removeAll(comboBox.getItems());
    comboBox.getItems().addAll("Option A", "Option B", "Option C");
    comboBox.getSelectionModel().select("Option B");
}
```